# How many server licenses do I need for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, licensing, sharepoint-2013

I am new to the concept of CAL. I am reading about it. I found this link  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101914/how-many-server-licenses-do-i-need-for-sharepoint-2013

Suppose there are 2 users in the sharepoint farm. As per above link we requires 7/8 server license. So my question is do we requires 7/8 licences per user basis (2*7/8) or we requires 7/8 licences once only then we require 2 more licenses for 2 users (7/8 +2)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing and not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second one is correct.

7 *  SharePoint servers = 7 * SharePoint Server Licenses

2 * people from company = 2 * Client Access Licenses

So You need 7 server 2 CAL.

From microsoft

> For On-Premises, intranet sites are licensed using a Server/CAL (Client Access License) model. SharePoint Server 2013 is required for each running instance of the software, and CALs are required for each person or device accessing a SharePoint Server.